# CSV , JAVA & HSQLDB

Tags: java, csv, hsqldb

im really new in java programming

i want to ask about reading a **CSV in java and then upload it to HSQLDB**.
i have been reading & try the example of solution through tutorial but still not really understand.
from my readings, **most had suggest of using OpenCSV** but

1. can i read a csv with delimiter or nested delimiter with opencsv?

   - opencsv reads my *.csv file in different way with multiple line in one column. all i want it to be read in a single row.

below is the example

B03BB510001T2001,,CHILDREN'S CHEWABLE MULTI VITAMINS*,,""PANTOTHENIC ACID 7.5MG,"
"PARA AMINO BENZOIC ACID (PABA) 250MCG,"
"FOLIC ACID 30MCG,"
"BIOTIN 50MCG,"
"THIAMINE MONO-NITRATE + B6 + B12 6.6MG,"
"CHOLINE 1MG,"
"VIT A + VIT E + VIT C REFER FILE,"
"INOSITOL 1MG"",,""TABLET, CHEWABLE"",,,,B03,REGISTERED,75MG"

BUT i want it to be displayed in **a single row**

1. how can i insert directly from csv file into database?

   - i am currently have to used HSQLDB [standalone server].
     do i have to used third party tools to do this

**i only familiar reading & upload from csv into database using PHP & MYSQL not java &hsqldb

hope you can suggest & help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample script I have used to load data into HSQL per fredt.  You will need to have a persistant DB to use a text table. If you run in the Database Manager just copy and execute one statement at a time.  You can also use sqltool (the sql script is in the same folder as the DB):

```
\i demotexttable.sql
```

Here is the demotexttable.sql

```
/* file.txt needs to be in the same folder as the database
   first line of file is a header, others lines are data
--start file.txt
Col1|Col2|Col3
abcdef|My Company Name|0
--end file.txt
*/

--create the schema
create schema imp;

--create the normal table
create cached table imp.normalTable (
       Col1 char(6),
       Col2 nvarchar(200),
       Col3 int
);

--create the table that table
create text table imp.textfiletable (
       Col1 char(6),
       Col2 nvarchar(200),
       Col3 int
);

--setup the text file table
set table imp.textfiletable source "file.txt;ignore_first=true;fs=|";

--insert data from text file into the `normal` table
INSERT INTO imp.normalTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) select Col1, Col2, Col3 from imp.textfiletable;

--we are done with the text file table
drop table imp.textfiletable;
commit;
```

I found a few errors in my earlier post, I have cleaned them up in this latest mod.

Comment: im sorry but the insert data from text into normal table syntax has error..
do i need o run it in sqltool?

Comment: thank you for cleaning simple error but
i have prob while using the INSERT STATEMENT
i had tried in my [latest post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152162/hsqldb-importing-a-text-table-file-into-a-traditional-table)
still having prob

Comment: Using this `set table imp.textfiletable source ...` clears the source file. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @zigimantus it shouldn't clear the source file unless you delete from it. You can also make the TEXT table readonly.

Answer (score 2):

You can load a CSV file directly into HSQLDB.

There are two different ways:

1. Use HSQLDB's TEXT TABLE feature. Your file shouldn't need any special setting as the delimiter is the default.
2. Use HSQLDB's normal tables and load the CVS with SqlTool, which is an additional jar supplied with HSQLDB. SqlTool can be used not only with HSLQLDB, but also with MySQL and other databases.

See here for details:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_csv-sect

Comment: 1. last time i tried to upload the data using insert extend - the hsqldb had problem with the nested delimiter like (",/"). did you mean, using **.txt** instead of **.csv** ?

2.mybe im the only one that stress out too much but don't know why, i don't understand  how to use the sqltool even refer to the Sample CSV export + import script :(

Comment: With TEXT tables, you need to create the table first. Try this and report your CREATE TABLE and the SET TABLE statements for help if it does not work.

Comment: But which of the two options are better if you will only query data?  Is there a performance difference?  does disk caching make querying the csv file just as fast as the memory table?  What other difference would there be?

Comment: Which option is better depends on memory allocation, etc. For reads, you can make TEXT tables almost as fast as memory tables. Otherwise memory tables are faster.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that CSV is nothing but a "Comma-Separated-Value". The reason why others suggested OpenCSV is because its has a commercially friendly license. Though apart from that one can use the normal way to retrieve the values.Which is read the values using FileInputStream.Please find the link:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml

After that parse the individual String using delimiter.
eg: String[] tokens = wholeString.split(delimiter);

Now simply using the jdbc connectivity through using java.sql package one can easily store the values in hsql database.Please check out the link:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apb.html

Hope this helps you out;
Regards,

Anand