# HSQLDB importing a text table file into a traditional table

Tags: hsqldb, bulkinsert

i have two the same table structure

1. cache table (normaltable)
2. text table (textfiletable)

**i want to copy data from table [2] into table [1]**

i'm using this insert syntax

```
INSERT INTO normaltable ("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM textfiletable;
```

i get this error

```
data exception:string data, right truncation/Error code: -3401/state: 22001
```

when using another insert syntax

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
INTO normaltable
FROM textfiletable;
```

i get this error

```
unexpected token : INTO required: FROM:line:2/error code: -5581/state:42581
```

can anybody explain?

---

im update the detail of my script for you to refer:

```
drop table pis_mdc;
drop table normaltable;
drop table textfiletable;

--- original table
CREATE TABLE PIS_MDC
(UD_MDC_CODE VARCHAR(25) ,
DRUG_GNR_NAME VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(100),
UD_MDC_DESC VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE VARCHAR(600),
DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE VARCHAR(200),
DOSAGE_FORM_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_DOSAGE VARCHAR(20),
DEF_ROUTE_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_ADVISORY_CODE VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
UD_ATC_CODE VARCHAR(15) ,
STATUS VARCHAR(20),
DRUG_STRENGTH VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(UD_MDC_CODE,UD_ATC_CODE));

--create cached tbl
create cached table normaltable
(UD_MDC_CODE VARCHAR(25) ,
DRUG_GNR_NAME VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(200),
UD_MDC_DESC VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE  VARCHAR(600),
DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE VARCHAR(200),
DOSAGE_FORM_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_DOSAGE VARCHAR (20),
DEF_ROUTE_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_ADVISORY_CODE VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
UD_ATC_CODE VARCHAR(15) ,
STATUS VARCHAR(20),
DRUG_STRENGTH VARCHAR(20));

--create the table that table
create text table textfiletable 
(UD_MDC_CODE VARCHAR(25) ,
DRUG_GNR_NAME VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(200),
UD_MDC_DESC VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE VARCHAR(600),
DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE VARCHAR(200),
DOSAGE_FORM_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_DOSAGE VARCHAR (20),
DEF_ROUTE_CODE VARCHAR(100)DEFAULT 'NULL',
DEF_ADVISORY_CODE VARCHAR(200)DEFAULT 'NULL',
UD_ATC_CODE VARCHAR(15) ,
STATUS VARCHAR(20),
DRUG_STRENGTH VARCHAR(20));


--SET TABLE textfiletable SOURCE ON

SET TABLE textfiletable SOURCE "gabung.csv;ignore_first=true"

--OPTION 0 line 1 with quotes without MAX(CHAR_LENGTH())
INSERT INTO normaltable ("UD_MDC_CODE","DRUG_GNR_NAME","DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME","UD_MDC_DESC","ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE","DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE","DOSAGE_FORM_CODE","DEF_DOSAGE","DEF_ROUTE_CODE","DEF_ADVISORY_CODE","UD_ATC_CODE","STATUS","DRUG_STRENGTH") 
select UD_MDC_CODE,DRUG_GNR_NAME,DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME,UD_MDC_DESC,ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE,DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE,DOSAGE_FORM_CODE,DEF_DOSAGE,DEF_ROUTE_CODE,DEF_ADVISORY_CODE,UD_ATC_CODE,STATUS,DRUG_STRENGTH 
from textfiletable;

-- OPTION 1 line 1 without quotes
--SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(COL1)), MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(COL2)), ... FROM textfiletable 
--INSERT INTO normaltable ("UD_MDC_CODE","DRUG_GNR_NAME","DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME","UD_MDC_DESC","ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE","DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE","DOSAGE_FORM_CODE","DEF_DOSAGE","DEF_ROUTE_CODE","DEF_ADVISORY_CODE","UD_ATC_CODE","STATUS","DRUG_STRENGTH")
INSERT INTO normaltable (UD_MDC_CODE,DRUG_GNR_NAME,DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME,UD_MDC_DESC,ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE,DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE,DOSAGE_FORM_CODE,DEF_DOSAGE,DEF_ROUTE_CODE,DEF_ADVISORY_CODE,UD_ATC_CODE,STATUS,DRUG_STRENGTH)
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(UD_MDC_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DRUG_GNR_NAME)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(UD_MDC_DESC)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(ACTIVE_INGREDIENT_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DEF_CAUTIONARY_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DOSAGE_FORM_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DEF_DOSAGE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DEF_ROUTE_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DEF_ADVISORY_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(UD_ATC_CODE)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(STATUS)),MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DRUG_STRENGTH))
FROM textfiletable
--ORDER BY UD_MDC_CODE DESC;

--we are done with the text file table
DROP TABLE  textfiletable;
COMMIT;
```

example list of data from textfiletable that want to be copy/insert into normaltable
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-7fkDVcLbxnclBZZDZRQWg4ZEE

example of result of using max(char_length(col_name))
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-7fkDVcLbxnREpzNUp3d3NNSlE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unexpected token` error is a syntax error. It means this syntax is not supported in version 2.x.

The `data exception` error means some string stored in the TEXT table is too large to insert into the field in the CACHED table. Try a query such as:

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(UD_MDC_CODE)), MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DRUG_GNR_NAME)), MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(DRUG_PRODUCT_NAME)) FROM textfiletable
```

look at the result and compare the maximum lengths with the column size of the `normaltable`. For example, if the MAX value for UD_MDC_CODE is 29, then you have to make this column larger. This can be done using this statement which changes the size of the column to 30:

```
ALTER TABLE normaltable ALTER COLUMN UD_MDC_CODE SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(30)
```

Use the ALTER TABLE statement only for columns that have a smaller size than the MAX value. When you have done this for all the columns that are too samll, use your INSERT INTO statement to copy the data from the TEXT table to the CACHED table. The ALTER TABLE statement is documented here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_manupulation

Comment: thanks for replyin but i already change the tables data type from **VARCHAR to LONGVARCHAR**
still its give error of `expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: PUBLIC.TEXTFILETABLE.UD_MDC_CODE / Error Code: -5574 / State: 42574 ` after set the `MAX(CHAR_L..)`

Comment: I edited the SELECT example. Just put your column names in place of COL1, CLO2 and COL3 and it will work.

Comment: does this mean i must use `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(COL))` at every column i have?

Comment: i just tried but it wasn't the way i wanted..
yes..it does update but it doesn't copy the data
it just show the total length of max_char in each column in a row

Comment: You do not insert the MAX results. Simply look at them to see which column is too small, then make the column larger.

Comment: im sorry, i just update the results
i already try by enlarge the datatype's length but its keep on giving the same err.
or maybe the INSERT STATEMENT is not suitable to do : copy data from text_table into traditional_table in HSQLDB?

Comment: You did not enlarge all the datatype length. DRUG_STRENGTH VARCHAR(20) but MAX length shows 29. Please check carefully.

Comment: im sorry for trouble you a lot.
i must have missed it
THANK YOU fredt!
(^_^)v